# Add JObject to JObject

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

I have a json structure like this:

```js
var json = 
{
  "report": {},
  "expense": {},
  "invoices": {},
  "projects": {},
  "clients": {},
  "settings": {
    "users": {},
    "companies": {},
    "templates": {},
    "translations": {},
    "license": {},
    "backups": {},
  }
}
```

I would like to add a new empty Object like "report":{} to the json

My C# code is like this:

```
JObject json = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("path"));
json.Add(new JObject(fm.Name));
```

But it it gives me a exception:

> Can not add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue to
> Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject

So, how can I add a new and empty JObject to the json

Thanks in advance

Comment: JObject doesn't have a constructor which takes JValue param. [https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm]

Comment: `json.Add(new JObject().Add("test",new JValue(fm.Name)));`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are trying to construct a `JObject` with a string (which gets converted into a `JValue`).  A `JObject` cannot directly contain a `JValue`, nor another `JObject`, for that matter; it can only contain `JProperties` (which can, in turn, contain other `JObjects`, `JArrays` or `JValues`).

To make it work, change your second line to this:

```
json.Add(new JProperty(fm.Name, new JObject()));
```

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cjtoJn

Answer (score 15):

One more example

```
var jArray = new JArray {
    new JObject
    {
        new JProperty("Property1",
            new JObject
            {
                new JProperty("Property1_1", "SomeValue"),
                new JProperty("Property1_2", "SomeValue"),
            }
        ),
        new JProperty("Property2", "SomeValue"),
    }
};
```

Answer (score 8):

```
json["report"] = new JObject
    {
        { "name", fm.Name }
    };
```

Newtonsoft is using more direct-like approach, where You can access any property via square brackets `[]`. You just need to set the `JObject`, which have to be created based on Newtonsoft specifics.

Full code:

```
var json = JObject.Parse(@"
{
    ""report"": {},
    ""expense"": {},
    ""invoices"": {},
    ""settings"": {
        ""users"" : {}
    },
}");

Console.WriteLine(json.ToString());

json["report"] = new JObject
    {
        { "name", fm.Name }
    };

Console.WriteLine(json.ToString());
```

Output:

```
{
  "report": {},
  "expense": {},
  "invoices": {},
  "settings": {
    "users": {}
  }
}

{
  "report": {
    "name": "SomeValue"
  },
  "expense": {},
  "invoices": {},
  "settings": {
    "users": {}
  }
}
```

As a reference, You can look at this link: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ModifyJson.htm