# Issue with Newtonsoft Json Linq in Powershell vs .NET?

Tags: powershell, json.net

I have the following code in a C# .NET App....

```
 JObject myJObject = new JObject();
 JArray myJArray = new JArray();

 myJObject.Add(
                (new JProperty("PropA", (new JObject(new JProperty("PropA1", "")))))
              );

 Console.WriteLine(myJObject.ToString());
```

It works as expected and the output I get is

**{
  "PropA": {
    "PropA1": ""
  }
}**

However, when I do the exact same code in Power shell (but translated)...

```
using namespace Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
Add-Type -Path "C:\Temp\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" 

[JObject] $myJObject = New-Object JObject
[JArray]  $myJArray = New-Object JArray

$myJObject.Add(
                (New-Object JProperty("PropA",(New-Object JObject((New-Object JProperty("PropA1",""))))))
              ) 

write-host $myJObject.ToString()
```

It blows up and I get the error..

**New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Can not add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject."**

Interesting enough, if I use that same code but add 2 properties it works...

```
  $myJObject.Add(
                 (New-Object JProperty("PropA",(New-Object JObject((New-Object JProperty("PropA1","")), (New-Object JProperty("PropA2",""))))))
                 )
```

but of course I get this...

**{
  "PropA": {
    "PropA1": "",
    "PropA2": ""
  }
}**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr**

```
using namespace Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
Add-Type -Path "C:\Temp\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" 

[JObject] $myJObject = New-Object JObject

$myJObject.Add(
  (New-Object JProperty "PropA",
                        (New-Object JObject (
                            # Note the , (...) around this New-Object call,
                            # which wraps the resulting JProperty instance in a 
                            # single-element array.    
                            , (New-Object JProperty "PropA1", "")
                          )
                        )
  )
)

$myJObject.ToString()
```

**Alternative**, using the **PSv5+ static `::new()` method** available on types for **calling constructors**:

```
[JObject] $myJObject = New-Object JObject

$myJObject.Add(
  [JProperty]::new("PropA",
    [JObject]::new(
      # No workaround needed.
      [JProperty]::new("PropA1", "")
    )
  )
)

$myJObject.ToString()
```

---

[Brian Rogers' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53218371/45375) was on the right track: the problem is that **the inner `JObject` constructor doesn't receive the `JProperty` instance being passed as an argument *as such*** when `New-Object` cmdlet calls are used.

```
# *Seemingly* the equivalent of: new JObject(new JProperty("PropA1", ""))
New-Object JObject (New-Object JProperty "PropA1", "") # !! FAILS
```

**Note the use of *shell-like syntax* - whitespace-separated arguments, no parentheses around the argument list** - because that's what a cmdlet such as `New-Object` expects - these are *not* method calls; they are PowerShell commands parsed in [*argument mode*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing).

**Wrapping the `JProperty` instance in a *helper array* fixes the problem**:

```
New-Object JObject (, (New-Object JProperty "PropA1", "")) # OK - wrapped in array
```

`,` is PowerShell's *array-construction operator*, so that `, <expr>` creates a single-element `object[]` array wrapping the result of `<expr>`.<sup>[1]</sup>

However, the **problem can be avoided to begin with by using the PSv5+ static `::new()` method for construction**; `::new()` is available on all types, and allows you to call constructors using *method syntax*:

```
[JObject]::new([JProperty]::new("PropA1", "")) # OK
```

---

**As for *why* a *scalar* `JProperty` argument doesn't work with `New-Object` in PowerShell**:

**Because the `JProperty` type implements the `IEnumerable` interface, PowerShell tries to *enumerate* a single `JProperty` instance rather than passing it as itself** when binding to the (implied) `-ArgumentList` parameter (which is itself `object[]`-typed).
This fails, because the `JObject` constructor then sees the result of that enumeration, which is a `JValue` instance representing the JSON property *value*, and constructing a `JObject` instance from a `JValue` instance isn't permitted, as reflected in the error message - see [Brian's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48171460/45375).

Wrapping such an instance in an array bypasses the problem: it prevents the enumeration of the `JProperty` instance and safely passes it through inside the auxiliary `object[]` instance.

If what you're passing to `New-Object JObject` is an array *to begin with*, such as your example of passing *two* `JProperty` instances, the problem is also avoided.

Also note that casting to `[JObject]` works too, but only with *one* property:

```
New-Object JObject ([JObject] (New-Object JProperty "PropA1", "")) # OK with 1 prop.
```

---

Not that **Powershell's has built-in JSON support**, which allows convenient conversion of hashtables and custom objects to JSON and back:

```
# Convert a nested hashtable to JSON
PS> @{ PropA = @{ PropA1 = 42 } } | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
{"PropA":{"PropA1":42}}

# Convert JSON to a custom object [pscustomobject] with property
# .PropA whose value is another custom object, with property .PropA1
PS> '{"PropA":{"PropA1":42}}' | ConvertFrom-Json

PropA
-----
@{PropA1=42}
```

So, unless you have special requirements and/or performance matters, PowerShell's built-in features may suffice, and, you can even convert custom objects / hashtables to `JObject` / `JToken` instances via a JSON string representation, albeit not cheaply:

```
PS> [JToken]::Parse((@{ PropA = @{ PropA1 = 42 } } | ConvertTo-Json -Compress)).ToString()
{
  "PropA": {
    "PropA1": 42
  }
}
```

---

[1] Note that `@(...)`, the array-subexpression operator, does *not* work robustly in this case, because it too involves unwanted *enumeration* of the `JProperty` instance before wrapping the result in an `[object[]]` array:

```
# !! FAILS too: 
# The JProperty instance is again enumerated, resulting in a single
# JValue instance, which is what @(...) then wraps in a
# single-element [object[]] array.
$var = New-Object JProperty "PropA1", ""
New-Object JObject @($var)
```

Curiously, you *can* get away with `@(...)` *if you directly place the `New-Object` call inside it*:

```
# !! Happens to work, but is OBSCURE.
# !! Equivalent of: (, (New-Object JProperty "PropA1", "")) 
New-Object JObject @(New-Object JProperty "PropA1", "")
```

That `@(...)` *prevents* enumeration in this case is owed to the fact that *command* output (e.g., `@(New-Object ...)`) - as opposed to *expression* output (e.g., `@($var)`) - is *not* enumerated by `@(...)`; that is, if the command outputs something that is enumerable / a collection *as a whole* - which is what `New-Object` does when instantiating such types - `@(...)` wraps it as-is in a single-element `[object[]]` array. (As an aside: `$(...)` *would* cause enumeration).

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that PowerShell is not resolving the correct `JObject` constructor for some reason, though I do not know why.  I played with your example for a while and was unable to coax PowerShell to do the right thing.

I would suggest rewriting your script so that you are creating your `JObjects` with the empty constructor, and then using the `Add` method to add properties to them.  I was able to get your desired output in this way:

```
$emptyVal = New-Object JValue ""
$innerObject = New-Object JObject
$innerObject.Add("PropA1", $emptyVal)
$myJObject = New-Object JObject
$myJObject.Add("PropA", $innerObject)

Write-Host $myJObject.ToString()
```

Comment: Thanks for trying it. I'm glad you saw the same thing I did because there are times I think I'm going crazy! Another work around I had found was to add both so it would get the correct OverLoad, and then go back and delete the second property so the end result is what I wanted.